# Help wanted re using Spyder2express calibrator with Windows 8

Tags: display-calibration

I recently acquired a ColorVision Spyder2express monitor calibrator.
This is an old entry level calibrator - but worth what I paid for it **IF** I can make it work at all.

I have Windows 8.0 on the PC I wish to use it with. I could use a Windows 7 netbook to do the calibration provided the Win8 PC can then use the result. (I do not yet know whether the result depends on a profile or is machine specific or ...)

WIN7 drivers are available.
WIN8 drivers less so. I found one site that claims to provide a WIN8 driver but I'm suspicious of the files it provides.

Any good advice? (apart from "throw it out and get a newer one" :-) )

Comment: I've got a Win8 Dell all-in-one and have it calibrated with a Spyder2Express.  Don't remember having any issues...

Comment: @ConorBoyd - Can you advise where you got the drivers from - that being the main issue

Comment: I haven't saved the driver/installer anywhere specifically that I can find.  Pretty sure I just installed version 2.3.6 from [here](http://support.datacolor.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1445/0/spyder2express-236---win) which explicitly states 64-bit Windows support (although doesn't explicitly state Windows 8.1 support).

Answer (score 1):

If the display you wish to calibrate isn't part of an integrated system such as a laptop or an all-in-one then yes, you could calibrate the display with your netbook and transfer the resulting .ICC colour profile to your Win 8 machine.

Answer (score -1):

spyder2 isn't able to calibrate LED backlight displays, only Spyder3 and 4 can do. Be aware of this too.

Comment: That conflicts with what I think I have learned so far: I downloaded the latest available Spyder2express Windows 64 bit driver driver from the manufacturer's website and the calibration procedure explicitly discussed contrast versus backlight control and gave instructions related to backlight equipped LCDs. | I have achieved a calibration result BUT I'm not sure (so far) how much what I've achieved is the result of the calibration and how much is my preparing for it - I'm still interested what other people have found and achieved.